# Root finding and finding the zero crossing of a ODE with SOLVE-IVP

Tags: python, root, ode, solver

I have been searching for a method to find the point in which a differential equation changes its sign, it can be zero crossing or root finding.

Some one told me to use `Brent's Method` but it was not accurate. For example the figure cuts the zero at `0.12` but the method obtains something like `0.19` or more which is not acceptable.

Now I found this algorithm [scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), in this method it is stated that `The solver looks for a sign change over each step, so if multiple zero crossings occur within one step, events may be missed.`

I did not understand how to do that.

Consider we have a differential equation

```
dE/dz = f(E,z)
```

we know the answer of `dE/dz`, we know the initial point `E0`  but we would like to know in which `z` we have the answer of `dE/dz`. so we should obtain the value of `z` which leads to the answer of `dE/dz`

Any help please?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the differential equation you are trying to solve? Is there a specific one or does it need to be generalized?

Comment: @JackMoody it is  `dE/dz = f(E,z)`. It can be every thing. For example 'dod/dz = ((c**2 - od)/(1+z)) * (3 * od + 6 - 9 * (od/c**2))/(1 + c**2 + od * (1 - 3/c**2))'

Comment: @JackMoody  in this equation, I know `dod/dz = 0.2` the initial point `od0=0.73` but I want to know in which `z` we get `dod/dz = 0.2`.  Brents method is not accurate.

Comment: Please give a more precise statement of what you want to solve. Do you want to solve `f(E(z),z)=f0` for `z` along some solution, or `f(E,z)=f0` for `E` given `z` or for `z` given `E`?

Comment: @LutzL As I mentioned in my question `z` is unknown for given `E`